# Flash/Haxe trace messages not showing in Flash Player

Tags: flash, debugging, trace, haxe

Writing Haxe in FlashDevelop. Recently upgraded a bunch of my librarys and Haxe to the latest versions, now suddenly my traces don't show up in the top left in Flash Player (on release mode in FlashDevelop). Trace's will show up in the console if I'm in debug mode, but having the traces show up in the Flash Player was more convenient for me. Can I get this back?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Release mode always excludes the traces, because you cannot trace in a release build.

So you always need to test in debug mode, which makes sense in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

It still works fine for me, but you can always work around it:

```
var textField:TextField = new TextField();
textField.width = stage.stageWidth;
textField.height = stage.stageHeight;
textField.mouseEnabled = false;
stage.addChild(textField);

Log.trace = function(value:Dynamic, ?infos:PosInfos):Void {
    textField.appendText(infos.fileName + ":" + infos.lineNumber + ": " + Std.string(value) + "\n");
}
```

(Periodically clearing the text field is left as an exercise for the reader.)